# Understanding how AppSync + S3 work together

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I try and succeed to upload a file using AWS Amplify quick start doc and I used this example to set my graphql schema, my resolvers and dataSources correctly: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-amplify-graphql.

I was stuck for a long time because of an error response "Access Denied" when my image was uploading into the S3 bucket. I finally went to my S3 console, selected the right bucket, went to the Authorization tab, and clicked on "Everyone" and finally selected "Write Object". With that done, everything works fine.
But I don't really understand why it's working, and Amazon show me a big and scary alert on my S3 console now saying "We don't recommend at all to make a S3 bucket public". 
I used Amazon Cognito userPool with Appsync and it's inside my resolvers that the image is upload to my S3 bucket if i understood correctly.

So what is the right configuration to make the upload of an image work?
I already try to put my users in a group with the access to the S3 bucket, but it was not working (I guess since the user don't really directly interact with my S3 bucket, it's my resolvers who do).

I would like my users to be able to upload an image, and after displaying the image on the app for everybody to see (very classical), so I'm just looking for the right way to do that, since the big alert on my S3 console seems to tell me that turning a bucket public is dangerous.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using an IAM role to upload files to S3. You can set the bucket policy to allow that role with certain permissions whether that is ReadOnly, WriteOnly, etc.

Take a look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find where it was going wrong. I was uploading my image taking the address of my S3 bucket with the address that was given by aws-exports.js.
BUT, when you go to your IAM role policy, and you check the role of your authorize  user of your cognito pool, you can see the different strategies and the one that allow to put objects on your S3 bucket use the folders "public", "protected" and "private". 
So you have to change those path or add these folder at the end of your bucket address you use on your front-end app.

Hope it will help someone!